# Like button showing same number of likes on different pages

Tags: facebook-like

I have a site problemio dot com (not posting url so it doesnt look like I am just trying to get links, etc.)

On the photo in the home page, there are 7 different links to categories. In each category there is the same number of likes. I don't understand why.

Here is the FB snippet I use:

```
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width: 100px; padding-left: 55px; padding-bottom: 15px;">
         <center><div id="fb-root"></div>
         <script>(function(d, s, id) {
           var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
           if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
           js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
           js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=234415063262341";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
         }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
         <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.problemio.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>  
         </center>               
        </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `data-href="http://www.problemio.com"` have to be a unique page?

like `data-href="http://www.problemio.com/category/photos"` and or

`data-href="http://www.problemio.com/about"`

so that way each page can be liked?

Answer (score 1):

Use each page's own canonical URL on each data-href.